# Windows 10 taking almost all disk space

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

After I upgraded to Windows 10, free disk space went from 100 GB to 5 GB on my 205 GB system disk over the course of about two months. I am not aware I installed any programmes that could cause such drop in free disk space.

I tried Disk Cleanup, but it did not free much disk space.

What are some tips reclaim the disk space on Windows 10?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The correct to tool to help answer this type of question is [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/). Run it as Admin.

Comment: @DanielB WinDirStat helped me solve the problem. In my case I had large SQL Server error log files on the disk.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik Make an answer for this then.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik This question has been marked as a duplicate, it cannot be answered anymore.

Answer (score 3):

When you upgrade to Windows 10, your existing Windows folder is renamed to **C:\windows.old**

Apparently this should be automatically removed after a month or so, but the following shows instructions for manually removing it, if you need the space...

The link to the article for manually removing is [Here](http://www.cnet.com/au/how-to/how-to-delete-the-windows-old-folder-from-windows-10/)